# How to return the paths of sub directories at maximum depth?

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk

Using `os.walk()`, I managed to return every sub directories at the maximum depth:

```
>>> import os
>>> sites = [x[0] for x in os.walk('./')]
>>> print(sites)
['./', './Saudi_arabia', './Saudi_arabia/Periodic_barchans', './Saudi_arabia/Finger_rocks', './Mars', './Niger', './Maroc', './Algeria', './China']
```

However, I'd like to filter the ones that have directories in themselves.
For example, `./Saudi_arabia/` should not appear because it contains `./Saudi_arabia/Periodic_barchans` and `./Saudi_arabia/Finger_rocks`.

How would you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out entries with non-empty lists of sub-directories, which are stored as the second items of the tuples generated by `os.walk`:

```
sites = [root for root, dirs, _ in os.walk('.') if not dirs]
```